# Group list of lists by Total

Tags: list-manipulation

I have some list which looks like

```
{{0,1},{4},{0,0,1},{2,0,1},{3,0,0},{3,1},{0,0,0,4}}
```

and I need to group lists with equal sum of elements in ascending order like

```
{{{0,1},{0,0,1}},{{2,0,1},{3,0,0}},{{4},{3,1},{0,0,0,4}}}
```

and for

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}
```

I expected to see

```
{{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Sort@GatherBy[{{0, 1}, {4}, {0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 0}, {3, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 4}}, Total]
```

To make sure `Sort` always gets it right:

```
Sort[GatherBy[n, Total], Less[Total@First[#], Total@First[#2]] &]
```

Comment: n = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}};
Sort@GatherBy[n, Total]; gives {{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}} but I would like to get {{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}

Comment: Yes, it was only plain luck that the first version worked without having to use `SortBy`. But that's exactly why I added another version which, as I said, "always gets it right." (In the first version it works because the first number in each sublist is ascending in the way you would like to have it sorted.

Comment: So just to be clear, the topmost solution is only valid for the first example you provided. Not for subsequent examples. But I foresaw this, and provided the first version only as a curiosity to show that in this particular case it's this simple.

Comment: Your second line appears to be a `SortBy[...,True]`. This just defaults down to `Sort` again and makes it equal to your first solution.

Comment: @jVincent Yeah, silly me. I corrected it. I sure would have appreciated some downvotes/comments to alert me! With seven upvotes you tend to think you have it right! Ty! (+1 for yours, I like it better. It should get at least 14 upvotes.)

Answer (score 7):

A simple approach is to just use:

```
GatherBy[SortBy[list,Total],Total]
```

This ensures that they appear in the correct order since they are gathered based on the appearance of the first element. In each sublist with the same total, they will be ordered based on `OrderedQ`, which puts them in order of number of elements afaik.

To verify that it works out:

```
 listA={{0,1},{4},{0,0,1},{2,0,1},{3,0,0},{3,1},{0,0,0,4}};
 listB={{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {4}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 0}, {3, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 4}};

verify[v_] := Total[First[#]] & /@ v
verify@GatherBy[SortBy[listA, Total], Total]
verify@GatherBy[SortBy[listB, Total], Total]
(* {1,3,4} *)
(* {1,3,4} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

I would write it like this:

```
list ~SortBy~ {Total} ~SplitBy~ Total
```

Note that putting the `SortBy` function inside a list (i.e. `{Total}` instead of just `Total`) means that `SortBy` will give a stable sort, so elements with the same total will stay in the order they were in the original list.

Comment: neat idea! Thanks for sharing/explaining

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun:

```
Pick[list, Total /@ list, #] & /@ Union[Total /@ list]
```

=> {{{0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{2, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 0}}, {{4}, {3, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 
   4}}}

where

```
list = {{0, 1}, {4}, {0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 0}, {3, 1}, {0, 0, 
   0, 4}}
```

And

```
Pick[n, Total /@ n, #] & /@ 
  Union[Total /@ n] == {{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1,
     0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}
```

=> True

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = {{0, 1}, {4}, {0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 0}, {3, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 4}};

Values @ SortBy[Total @ First @ # &] @ GroupBy[Total] @ lst
```

> {{{0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{2, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 0}}, {{4}, {3, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 
>      4}}}

Answer (score 1):

```
lst[[#]] & /@ Values[KeySort[PositionIndex[Total[lst, {2}]]]]
```

> {{{0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{2, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 0}}, {{4}, {3, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 4}}}

Since 11.2 also

```
With[{sums = Total[lst, {2}]},
 TakeList[lst[[Ordering[sums]]], Values[KeySort[Counts[sums]]]]]
```